# @PostConstruct for Maven components

Tags: maven, guice, sisu

Is there a way to make `@PostConstruct` (JSR-250) work on custom components injected into a custom Maven plugin?

I've found a reference to a [LifecycleModule](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386446) in Sisu, but it seems this is disabled in Maven by default, and I don't know how to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mycila jsr250 extension](https://github.com/mycila/guice#3-jsr-250) for guice. I followed the documentation an that site and it was fairly easy to use @PostConstruct afterwards. Mycila internally uses the sisu builds of guice.

One drawback is, that @PostConstruct only works for @Singletons ... but thats ok if your beans are stateless ...

Comment: Does that work in a Maven plugin when the creation of the Guice Injector is not under my control?

Comment: As long as you have control over the modules used to created the injector, I can't see how it wouldn't. But I didn't try it with maven plugins.